# How to unhide rows in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, row

I tried putting together a code for a checkbox which will unhide a row on another sheet based on value on column A on that sheet. Now what I want to do is unhide the following 3 rows underneath the target row. I can't specify row numbers because there is an option in the sheet to add more rows so column A entries may change row address.

Here's what I have working to unhide just that specific row with the entry on column A.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Budget")
        For Each c In .Range("A4:A1000" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            If IsError(c) Then c.Value2 = "1000L"  'Hides errors as well
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = (c.Value = "1000L" And .CheckBox1.Value) = False
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What can I add so it unhides the following 3 rows (will have empty entries on column A)?

Comment: `c.Resize(4).EntireRow.Hidden = ...`

Comment: Thanks. Had to modify my workbook so data is now in 2 sheets. I tried modifying but is not working..can you take a look?

Comment: Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim c As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Budget")
        For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vendor Cost").Range("A4:A1000" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vendor Cost").Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
            If IsError(c) Then c.Value2 = "1000L"  'Hides errors as well
            c.Resize(4).EntireRow.Hidden = (c.Value = "1000L" And ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Budget").CheckBox1.Value) = False
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: If you have code to add to your question, please edit the post (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75179084/edit) and add it there - it's not readable in a comment.  If you're having a problem with the new code, please explain the exact problem, rather than just "not working"